# Flutter - How to Update Home Route After Returning from MaterialPageRoute

Tags: flutter

This is my App's flow:

[image: App's Flow]

How do I update the Home Page when I press back and return to it from the MaterialPageRoute? I attempted to use the `setState` method in the `dispose()` method of MaterialPageRoute, but it gave me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the Home Page **is automatically updated**, however I made a mistake by updating the variable within the `dispose()` method, which is invoked after the Home Page has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TheSecondPage())).then((value) { setState(() {});` thus when you pop from `TheSecondPage()` you will immediatelly call the `setState` refreshing the page.